# Change Color of Highmap Areas based on database values

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, highcharts

everyone,

this is my first post on Stackoverflow - so sorry if I didn't follow certain conventions.

Following question:
I want to use a custom highmap on my web application in the future. My question is if I can change the color of the different areas of my map based on values of a MYSQL table.

For example, I want the areas to always be green until the value "1" instead of "0" is entered in the database table for a specific column.

Is this basically possible? Unfortunately I could not find the answer online.

I am grateful for any help!

Comment: Do you want create a table with a different background color?

Comment: Hey, no. I want to change the color of the specific areas dynamically based on a value in a MySQL table column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you provide the data correctly to your frontend, you will be able to use `dataClasses` property to achieve the wanted result.

```
colorAxis: {
  dataClasses: [{
    color: '#fff',
    to: 1
  }, {
    color: 'green',
    from: 1
  }]
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5L0r3xck/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/colorAxis.dataClasses

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a "dirty" code in order to show the idea.
You can get a value of color and add CSS class if the value is equal to 1.

```css
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<?php

// Example of DB data
// colors table
 -------------
|color | value|
 -------------
|green |  1   |
 -------------

// query
$sql = "SELECT value FROM colors WHERE color='green'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $className = '';
    if ($row['value'] === 1) {
      $className = 'green'
    }
    print("<td class="className">Some text</td>);
}
```